# Swipe gesture not changing UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to populate a uitableview with a bunch of cells, and then upon swiping one of the cells shifting just the individual cell to be populated by a different nib.  When I swipe the cell nothing is happening.  Below is the code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //below registers the nib's for the contact cell
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "ContactCell", bundle: nil)

    self.myTableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ContactCell
    //below gets the index
    var val = indexPath.row

    //below assigns the values of the fields on the cell
    cell.contactName.text = (name[val])
    return cell

     let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture))
     swipeLeft.direction = .left
     self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

     let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture))
     swipeRight.direction = .right
     self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Below is the function for being called:

```
func handleGesture(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer, indexNum: IndexPath) -> Void {
        if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right {
            //sets the nib2 = to the cell for right swipe, which is then called in CellForRowAt
            print("Swipe Right")
            let nib2 = UINib(nibName: "RightOptionCell", bundle: nil)
            self.myTableView.register(nib2, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell2")
            let cell2 = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexNum) as! LeftOptionCell
        }
        else if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left {
            //display the leftoptioncell
            print("Swipe Left")
            let nib2 = UINib(nibName: "DropDownOptionsCell", bundle: nil)
            self.myTableView.register(nib2, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell2")
            let cell2 = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexNum) as! DropDownOptionsCell
        }
    }
```

Nothing is executing upon swiping the cell, any thoughts as to why this may be

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you are adding the gesture recognizer to your view.  That means it detects swipes in your view and not on your tableViewCells; thats not necessarily a problem except that then you need to do the math to figure out which cell was swiped on.

The second problem is that the signature for your handler is wrong; the handler can either take no parameters or it can take one parameter and it must be the gesture recognizer; you have an index path on there and its not going to work.

Generally speaking the most common way to handle this case is to put the swipe gesture recognizer in the tableViewCell and have the cell inform its delegate (which should be your view controller) when the swipe occurs.  The viewController then modifies your model and calls reloadCell with come animation and that triggers cellForRowAt which will provide a new cell based on your updated model.